# update multiple rows with joins

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this query in postgresql:

```
select *
from A s
join B m on (s.id=m.id)
where m.key=4 and s.ran=some_input_from_user
```

This gives me all the rows that I need to update.

I want to set `A.value` to be `90` for all these rows.

It doesn't look like a standart update query

if I do...

```
Update A set value=90 where.....
```

then I can't do the join.

any ideas how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the basic update syntax for PostgreSQL where you are updating based on a join to another table:

```
update A s
set
  value = 90
from B m
where
  s.id = m.id and
  m.key = 4 and
  s.ran = some_input_from_user
```

The trick is you never use the alias in the lvalue for the `set` commands.  In other words, `value = 90` is not `s.value = 90`.  It seems minor, but I'm pretty sure it will prevent your query from working.  The rationale is if you are updating table A (alias s) then any fields you are updating are, de-facto, from table A -- no need to alias them, and to allow aliases would almost imply you could update something other than A with this statement, which you cannot.

You can definitely use them in the rvalues, so this would certainly be okay (if it were your desire to update A based on B):

```
update A s
set
  value = m.salary * s.commission
from B m
where
  s.id = m.id and
 (s.value is null or
  s.value != m.salary * s.commission)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the query:

```
update a set value = 90 
where exists (
         select 1 from b 
         where a.id = b.id and b.key=4 
         and a.ran=some_input_from_user);
```

The above query will eliminate the requirement of reading table a twice.

Also you can use this query:

```
update a set value = 90 
where a.id in 
  (select b.id from b 
   where a.id = b.id and b.key = 4 
   and a.ran=some_input_from_user);
```

Comment: I'm not sure how this is going to work? Select 1? How does it know what records to update?

Comment: In a semi-join (`exists`) the syntax is sort of funny.  What you select doesn't matter because you are only testing the existence of a corresponding record.  He could have just as easily said `select null` or `select 'frog'`.  It takes some getting used to, but semi-joins (and anit-joins) are very efficient.  These both look like good answers.

Answer (score -1):

TRY THIS

```
UPDATE A
SET A.VALUE = 90
from A
join B m on (A.id=m.id)
where m.key=4 and s.ran=some_input_from_user
```

Comment: Downvoted as "Try this" is not a "good answer" http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256359/flag-try-this-code-answers-as-very-low-quality

Comment: This is actually not valid syntax for PostgreSQL